# How can export a form into access 2013 from access 2003

Tags: ms-access-2013

I have a Form in access 2003, and I need it in access 2013, I think there are a possibility to export this form, from access 2003 and import into access 2013, or I must to create it??? So looks the the old project

[image]

I have also the module, I want to copy all functionality, thank you a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

You can import the form and module from the 2003 file into the 2013 database by doing these steps. First, close the 2003 database if you have it open. Next, open the 2013 database and then click External Data > Access on the Import & Link ribbon group. When the import dialog comes up, choose the option to import objects (it will be the default) and then browse to the location of the 2003 database. Click Ok when ready and you'll next see an Import Objects dialog come up which has tabs for the various object types in that database. Just select the objects you want to import and then click OK.

Comment: thank you for answer but don't work, I can not import so a form

Comment: I think you'll need to give us a lot more information than what you have if you want us to pinpoint the problem. "Don't work" is very vague. Do you get an error message when you try to import the objects? If so, what is the exact error message. Can you list the exact steps you are doing? Extra screenshots would be useful too.

Comment: Now I insert another image, the old access project have many forms, I need only one form with all functionality to use into my new access 2013 project, I think this is possible to do, but I don't find how to do it step by step

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem so:

1. I created a new access 2003 project database "TmpAccess"
2. I copied all forms, modules, ... all that I need, into my new project "TmpAccess"
3. I created a new access project 2013 and I open project "TmpAccess", so I used a form with all functionality from 2003 access project into access 2013 project. thank you **Jeff Conrad**